# Unable to install wine Xubuntu 16.04 64bits

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, wine

I know there are several question about this subject, but some of them do not have any response, and for the ones which do, I have followed all the advices given and nothing fixed my problem. Every time I attempt to give :

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

I get an error about **depends on X BUT IT WONT BE INSTALLED** with X being some version of wine, for instance wine1.6 or some library its using. I have attempted a MYRIAD of workarounds from all over Google but still I am unable to do it. As a side note, I used the same DVD to install Xubuntu on my mother's PC and I installed it there (Wine) with no issues.

Can someone advice here?

EDIT :  Error I am getting :

```
sudo apt-get install wine

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Attempting wine1.6

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
           Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Attempting wine1.6-amd64

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6-amd64
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6-amd64 : Depends: wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
                 Recommends: libosmesa6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Knowing the exact error message would help a lot.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I just happen to be at work now, but as soon as I am home ill post the exact error. Its basically what I posted.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have edited the post with some of the errors I am getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this following steps to download wine:

1. Add the PPA via command:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   ```
2. Update package cache and install wine1.8:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks
   ```

Install latest Wine Dev release from the Official WineHQ PPA:

Open terminal from Unity Dash, App Launcher, or via Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut key. When it opens, paste below commands and run one by one.

1. For 64-bit system, rum command to enable 32 bit architecture:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```

Type in your password when it asks, no visual feedback so type in mind and hit Enter to continue.

2. Add the wine PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
   ```
3. Once you have the PPA added in your system, run below commands one by one to refresh package caches and install Wine 1.8:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
   ```

   The installation automatically replaces old wine releases installed on your system.
4. Finally you may run below command to initialize your wine configuration.

   ```
   winecfg
   ```

Comment: When I run the very first command I get this :

Comment: !!! PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED !!!

In fact, it's double deprecated -- it was replaced by the Wine Builds PPA, which was then itself replaced.

For more information, please see:

    https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html

Comment: Should I add it anyway?